# Trying to make OneDrive connector in Windows Form app

Tags: winforms, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I am making a WinForm application using C#. When i try to connect OneDrive using SharePoint Client Object Model it gives me an error of "Value cannot be null".

Please guide me where i am making mistake. I need guidance on this.

```
      private void GetClientContext()
    {
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://techiesworld-my.sharepoint.com/"))
        {
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            //passtxt.Text = passWord.ToString();

            //foreach (char c in passtxt.Text.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(accountxt.Text, passWord);

            Web web = clientContext.Web;

            clientContext.Load(web);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            MessageBox.Show(web.Title);


        }
```

I am getting exception on clientContext.ExecuteQuery() function.

Comment: Please post your code, not screenshot of code. This can save whoever trying to help some typing. By the way, from which line is this exception thrown?

Comment: I have edited my question. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Ok, is it because the password cannot be empty? I mean the SecureString instance is not set with proper value.

Comment: I tried editing the Secure String instance and inserted correct password. It now gives me title of the web as i have put in MessageBox. Does this mean OneDrive has been connected???